# Can I have one external MVC solution in Sitecore Solution

Tags: sitecore-client

I know this is a weird question, but I was wandering to get this. I have a different published MVC solution. And I want to put that in a folder of my Sitecore application.

I was trying with the custom route pipeline.

In the folder named customAPI I have a separate published .NET MVC solution.

```
namespace CustomPipelines
{
    public class RegisterCustomRoute
    {
        public virtual void Process(PipelineArgs args)
        {
            Register();
        }

        public static void Register()
        {
            RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute("CustomRoute", "customapi/{controller}/{action}");
        }
    }
}



 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <pipelines>
            <initialize>
                <processor type="CustomPipelines.RegisterCustomRoute, MahindraAuto" patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes, Sitecore.Mvc']"/>
            </initialize>
        </pipelines>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Is it even possible?

Comment: As in a separate non-sitecore MVC application?

Comment: yes. It is totally a different solution. If I am putting an html, it is working, but a routing from a different solution is not picking up.

Comment: Unable to test this now but can you try to add customAPI to the IgnoreUrlPrefixes, that way Sitecore should ignore it. Is the folder a virtual directory?

Comment: Its is a folder making an application in web app.

Answer (score 1):

If its a separate application that is not connected to Sitecore in anyway, then you can use a virtual folder or application in IIS to set it up, and then you simply need to add that folder name to the `IgnoreUrlPrefixes` setting in Sitecore.

```
<setting name="IgnoreUrlPrefixes" value="/customapi|/sitecore/default.aspx|/trace.axd|/webresource.axd|/sitecore/shell/Controls/Rich Text Editor/Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx|/sitecore/shell/applications/content manager/telerik.web.ui.dialoghandler.aspx|/sitecore/shell/Controls/Rich Text Editor/Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd|/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd|/sitecore/admin/upgrade/|/layouts/testing"/>
```

That setting is a little hard to patch nicely. But there is a good solution here for that: https://firebreaksice.com/sitecore-patchable-ignore-lists/